# Force Ubuntu server locale to Windows client

Tags: networking, server, windows, samba, locale

I'm trying to setup Ubuntu server as domain controller using samba and it all works great. I can login, get personalized settings and user directory pathed in the clients at login. **All except for one thing, the locales on clients (1 x Windows XP & 1 x Windows 7) are forced to US locales(keymapping being the most annoying).**

During client installation I've chosen Swedish settings in both language and keymap(also removed the English ones).**I've changed the locales on the server to sv_SE.UTF-8 just in case the server forces it through that way.** But still no luck. I can change it locally on the client but i want to learn how to make the server to keep the settings instead.

I am pretty comfortable using Windows server & clients but kind of new to Linux.
I've read a lot of documentation and still not found anything useful.

**The question really is: 
Can you make the server to push locales to the clients ?**

Sorry for any grammatical errors and bad/wrong information given.
Looking forward to any reply that can help me along to any information regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

you might find your answer and lots of other useful info by following this link

[Ubuntu Server Guide - Windows Networking](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-dc.html)

Good luck and keep us posted.

Comment: Thanks for direction, have now read a for a full hour and a half and still nothing that helps with the locales. Going to keep reading and see what i find.
Edit: Thanks once again :)

Comment: You are welcome. I will run a similar setup in VM, and see what happens. I have only setup English locales.

Comment: Have now been through almost the whole samba documentation and still nothing that changes locales on windows clients. But i'm still looking and trying.
Noticed that numlock is also always off strangely enough but that's a different problem haha.
Edit: accidentaly hit send, thanks for helping out can't stop thinking about this >_<
Will post when i find something